# Simplest way to SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE mydate is in specific week number?

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, week-number

Is there a simpel way to select and sum rows where the date is in a specific week number?

Something like this code?

```
mysum = RS.execute("Select Sum(mypoints) as sumpoints from MyTable WHERE 
  datepart(week, mydate) = '42'")("sumpoints")
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Define what *you* mean by week.  (3) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Using MS Access database. Week is weeknumber (1-52) - in my asp file using vbscript I get good results with this formula: datepart("ww",date(),1,0).

Comment: I have lets say 100 records in my database and need to find for example the 5 records where the date coulumn "mydate" is in week 42.

Comment: Tried also the extract(week FROM mydate) without any luck.

Comment: `DatePart()` should be what you need. What is wrong with the results that you are getting? Also, which day do you want a week to start (Sunday, Monday, other)?

Comment: The *Interval* must be a string constant, meaning that is has to be enclosed in quotes. For *week*, you could use 'ww'. And the `42` should not be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for SQL statement and DatePart() function - uses default first day of week of Sunday:

`SELECT Sum(mypoints) AS sumpoints FROM MyTable WHERE DatePart("ww", mydate) = 42`

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have *Monday* as the first day of the week, it would be:

```sql
Select Sum(mypoints) As sumpoints 
From MyTable 
Where DatePart('ww', mydate, 2) = 42
```

However, if you need exact *ISO 8601* week numbering, you will have to use a custom function like this:

```vb
Public Function ISO_WeekNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date) _
  As Byte

' Calculates and returns week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' 1998-2000, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53

  Dim bytWeek                   As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(Year(datDate), 12, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000 bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekNumber = bytWeek

End Function
```

to replace *DatePart*.

Do note, that you will also have to filter on the year, as ISO weeknumbers 1 and 52/53 typically will cross calendar year boundaries.

**Addendum**:

This is the *VBScript* version in case the *VBA* version (above) can't be used:

```vb
Option Explicit

MsgBox ISO_WeekNumber(Date)

WScript.Quit


Function ISO_WeekNumber(ByVal Date1)

' Calculates and returns week number for date Date1 according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' 2019, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const FirstWeekOfAnyYear = 1
  Const LastWeekOfLeapYear = 53

  Dim Week
  Dim ISOThursday
  Dim LastDayOfYear

  Week = DatePart("ww", Date1, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If Week = LastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    ISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    LastDayOfYear = DateSerial(Year(Date1), 12, 31)
    If Weekday(LastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= ISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for VBA bug.
      Week = FirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekNumber = Week

End Function
```

Comment: Can that still be called from an MSAccess SQL query inside a Classic ASP page?

Comment: I don't know. I don't do Classic ASP, sorry, but I've appended the VBS version just in case, for use in a script. In any case, judging from your name, you _will_ need the ISO 8601 weeknumber, thus you _will_ need the extended syntax for `Weekday` and `DatePart` and a function similar to what I've posted here.

Comment: @Lankymart: See my comment above, please.